# Pandas many-to-many lookup between dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, many-to-many

I'm trying to pull together complex information on computer names, which department it belongs to, what service does it provide. I couldn't find answer or a similar question for that matter, and pandas documentation on **pd.merge()** is not clear to me.

I have a dataframe named **server_list**, where **each server appears multiple times**:

```
  Server     Platform    Package    Version
0 UK1010     Unix        Java       1.1
1 UK1010     Unix        Java       4.1
2 UK1010     Unix        Java       5.0
3 UK1011     Windows     Java       1.2
4 UK1011     Windows     Java       4.4
...
```

and I have a dataframe named **applications** which looks like this:

```
  Server     Department    Application    Environment
0 UK1010     Accounting    TaxMe          PROD
1 UK1010     Audit         TaxCheck       PROD
2 UK1010     CustomerForm  FillIt         PROD
...
```

**each server has multiple relationships to department, application, environment**

What I'm looking to achieve is many-to-many relationship, where I can pull all information (all rows) from **application**, and somehow marry it up with **server_list** so the items repeat, unless there is a better way? This is what I'm hoping to achieve, but not sure how to set up **pd.merge()** if this is the right approach:

```
  Server     Platform    Package    Version   Department   Application  Environment
0 UK1010     Unix        Java       1.1       Accounting   TaxMe        PROD
1 UK1010     Unix        Java       1.1       Audit        TaxCheck     PROD
2 UK1010     Unix        Java       1.1       CustomerForm FillIt       PROD
3 UK1010     Unix        Java       4.1       Accounting   TaxMe        PROD
4 UK1010     Unix        Java       4.1       Audit        TaxCheck     PROD
5 UK1010     Unix        Java       4.1       CustomerForm FillIt       PROD
6 UK1010     Unix        Java       5.0       Accounting   TaxMe        PROD
```

Can this be achieved? If, so how this problem should be approached? (Sorry if this question is dim, I'm new to data analysis using python)

Comment: Should be as simple as `df1.merge(df2)`.  I'll find a dupe target.

Comment: without passing any options whatsoever?

Comment: By default the merge finds commonly named columns.

Comment: `combined = server_list.merge(applications, how='left')` will ensure every server from `server_list` appears in your output frame. `how='right'` would ensure every application appears in your frame.

Comment: @asongtoruin this didn't work for me as it merged only one row for each server from applications, is there any way to get all rows?

Comment: I get exactly your desired result, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Out of 19750 unique servers in **server_list** the **combined** dataframe has only 1700, where application has all 19750 unique servers with several records for each of them. My **combined** has only 30200 records in total.

Comment: Thank you all. Suggested approach works alright. The flaw I had with merge not marrying all data was due to fact the one dataframe had keys as lower and upper case, where the other one had just upper. After normalising keys in both dataframe worked great.